# Python: How to increment the count when a variable repeats

Tags: python

I have a txt file which has following entries:

```
Rx = 34                  // Counter gets incremented = 1, since the Rx was found for the first time 
Rx = 2
Rx = 10
Tx = 2
Tx = 1
Rx = 3                   // Counter gets incremented = 2, since the Rx was found for the first time after Tx
Rx = 41
Rx = 3
Rx = 19
```

I want to increment the count only for the 'Rx' that gets repeated for the first time and not for all the Rx in the text file My code is as follows:

```
import re

f = open("test.txt","r")
count = 0

for lines in f:
    m = re.search("Rx = \d{1,2}", lines)
    if m:
        count +=1

print count
```

But this is giving me the count of all the Rx's in the txt file. I want the output as 2 and not 7.

Please help me out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

f = open("test.txt","r")
count = 0

for lines in f:
    m = re.search("Rx = \d{1,2}", lines)
    if m:
        count +=1
    if count >=2:
        break

print(m.group(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

break the loop since you only needs to find out repeats.

```
import re

f = open("test.txt","r")
count = 0

for lines in f:
    m = re.search("Rx = \d{1,2}", lines)
    if m:
        count +=1
    if count >=2:
        break
print count
```

Comment: This would always output 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: I think the desired output would be `m.group(0)`. I put this as a separate answer but if you edit your post I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 0):

By saying `if m:` it's going to continue to increment count as long as `m != 0`. If you'd like to only get the first 2, you need to introduce some additional logic.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find the count for the Rxes that are repeated 1x :

```
import re
rx_count = {}
with open("test.txt","r") as f:
    count = 0
    for lines in f:
        if line.startswith('Rx'): rx_count[lines] = rx_count.get(lines,0)+1
```

now you have a counter dictionary in rx_count and we filter out all the values greater than 1, then sum those values together , and print out the count

```
rx_count = {k:v for k,v in rx_count.interitems() if v > 1}
count = sum(rx_count.values())

print count
```

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly what you want, you're going need to keep track of which strings you've already seen.

You can do this by using a set to keep track of which you have seen until there is a duplicate, and then only counting occurrences of that string.

This example would do that

```
import re

count = 0
matches = set()

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search(r"Rx = \d{1,2}", line)
        if not m:
            # Skip the rest if no match
            continue

        if m.group(0) not in matches:
            matches.add(m.group(0))
        else:
            # First string we saw
            first = m.group(0)
            count = 2
            break

    for line in f:
        m = re.search(r"Rx = \d{1,2}", line)
        ## This or whatever check you want to do
        if m.group(0) == first:
            count += 1

print(count)
```